# Make CLion for C and not C++

Tags: c, clion

It looks to me that CLion understands C and C++ interchangeable. So as it happens, I need to work on 100% C code, code that will compile with C only compilers.

I've tried whatever I found online but I still manage to sneak in C++ code and CLion doesn't complain. I'd love if CLion could forget how to C++.

Comment: maybe you can edit CMakeLists.txt and change from g++ to gcc?

Comment: If CLion uses gcc/clang compiler, there's an option to specify the language. For example: `gcc -x c main.cpp` will compile `main.cpp` as a C file. How to set `-x` option in CLion is another story though.

Comment: I think this is the reponsibility of your compiler, not the IDE

Comment: @arved don't take offense as none is given. As you said, it is an IDE: "Integrated Development Environment". Keyword: integrated. That's how CLion sells itself. "CLion knows your code through and through and takes care of the routine while you focus on the important things".